# Decrypt .gpg/.pgp file without a prompt

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I've decrypted a file successfully using:

```
gpg --encrypt --recipient user@company.com myfile.txt
```

If I run the command below, I'm prompted for a passphrase, and decryption works:

```
gpg --output decrypted_myfile.txt -decrypt myfile.txt.gpg
```

I can't seem to get any form of non-interactive decryption working.  The closest I've come is:

```
gpg --decrypt --batch --passphrase MYPASSPHRASE myfile.txt.gpg
```

This gives me:

```
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID F6CF3C25, created 2016-03-17
      "Company_20210316 (Incoming Files) <user@company.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Bad passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: Could your passphrase contain special characters interpreted by the command line?

Comment: A similar conversation with an answer for gpg version 2.x is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415064/8926

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having error like: `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key` simply means that you don't have a private or secret key in your gpg keyring. You may want to check first if `gpg -k` (same as `gpg --list-keys`) has a private key there and import it and then trust it,

To add trust, use "1 to 5":

```
gpg --key-edit <yourKey>
```

then `trust` then `5` then `quit

To get your keyID run:

```
gpg --edit-key <yourKey>
```

then first line you'll see: `Private key available`
then two sub-keys on the left of the fist you'll see
`sec rsa2048/E7E43C5C844E2917`
and the part on a right after slash - will be your `<keyID> E7E43C5C844E2917`
so, to explicitly export from where it was generated, the key to a file you need to use that  like:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor E7E43C5C844E2917>yourSecretKey.asc
```

this will create secret key in a file ONLY, unlike if you use keyname in the export call then it will contain more than that.

Then to import use:

```
gpg --import E7E43C5C844E2917
```

then check your key in the list updated. Add trust if needed.

Then line to decrypt copied from terminal of my MAC and tested works, w/ no prompt:

```
gpg --batch --passphrase MyPassphrase -o test.tt7 -d CE.txt.gpg
```

NOTE that: `-d` is the same as `--decrypt` just like `-o` is the same as `--output`

Answer (score 0):

Having error like:
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

simply means that you don't have a private or secret key in your gpg keyring. You may want to check first if:

- gpg --list-secret-keys if it has a private key there and if not,

Import it and then trust it.

To trust, use:

```
gpg --key-edit <yourKey> then "trust" then "5" then "quit"
```

To get your keyID run:

```
gpg --edit-key <yourKey> then
```

On the first line you'll see: "Private key available"
Then two sub-keys on the left of the fist, you'll see similar to:

```
sec rsa2048/E7E43C5C844E2917
```

and the part on a right after slash - will be your

```
E7E43C5C844E2917
```

So to explicitly export from where it was generated, the key to a file, you need to use that  like this:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor E7E43C5C844E2917>yourSecretKey.asc
```

This will create a secret key in a file ONLY, unlike if you use keyname in the export call. Then it will contain more than that.
Then to import use:

```
gpg --import yourSecretKey.asc
```

Then check your key in the list updated. Add a trust if needed.

Then line to decrypt copied from terminal of my MAC and tested works, w/ no prompt:

```
 gpg --batch --passphrase MyPassphrase -o test.tt7 -d CE.txt.gpg
```

NOTE that: -d is the same as --decrypt and

```
        -o the same as --output
```

And the value of the passphrase is the actual value I used in my test to decrypt the above and not the variable. The same created during the time key generated, and actual recommendation is to use a longer set of characters but actually any number is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem you have is because the default keyring is being called by gpg, which is prompting for the password... use the below command to get what you need, I hope this could help you.

```
$ gpg --batch --no-default-keyring --no-keyring --passphrase="<your-passphrase>" -r <your-key-id> -d <your-encrypted-file>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this command:

```
gpg --output File.txt --batch--passphrase-fd YourPassword  --decrypt file.pgp
```